# Pattern for making sure the exact word won't be matched

Tags: regex, mariadb

I have a MySQL query that should check if each each row contains the following pattern:

```
red[^,]*car
```

Let's say I have these rows:

> this is a red car
>   red car it is
>   i like the red car a lot
>   red car

How can I change my current pattern to match all of the example rows except when there's an exact match (ie. the last line)?

Desired output:

Should return these rows:

> this is a red car
>   red car it is
>   i like the red car a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.red[^,]*car|red[^,]*car.
```

The idea is there should be at least one character (`.`) either (`|`) before or after your pattern, thus it wont do exact matches.

Comment: **except when there's an exact match (ie. the last line)** ... Your regex matches all of that string

Comment: @Shafizadeh No, test it against that string only, not the whole lise at once... the use of `[^,]*` matches the new lines and gives a fake/wrong match !!

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure what OP want .. But I hardly think he want [this](https://regex101.com/r/jW0eB4/1)

Comment: @Shafizadeh, as previously stated, check [this](https://regex101.com/r/jW0eB4/2) out.

Comment: @ndn Thanks. That seems to work, but could I adapt that pattern to work with regexp? Since it doesn't allow repetition-operators? Or is it not possible

Comment: @Cornwell, what do you mean regexp doesn't allow repetition?

Comment: @ndn I get this error when I try to run a mysql query with that pattern.
"SQL Error (1139): Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp"

Comment: @Cornwell, I didn't see it's mysql regex when I initially answered. Will update shortly.

Answer (score 0):

So it should be a match if they are not "alone".

The following regex will test if it's followed OR preceeded by a letter, then it will match:

```
[a-zA-Z]\s+(red[^,]*car)|(red[^,]*car)\s+[a-zA-Z]
```

If you think that the presence of any other char (including ponctuation) should give a match, then replace `[a-zA-Z]` with `\S`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
(.+red car.+|red car.+|.+red car)
```